# growl example windows 7

Tags: growl, growl-for-windows

I grabbed the growl for .NET on this page http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/developers.aspx

i ran the examples and nothing happened. Am i suppose to do something before running the example? I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that project is an example of how to *send* a notification. in order for anything to happen, you also have to have something to *receive* the notification. in other words, you have to have Growl for Windows installed and running as well.

Comment: I dont remember the original problem but last time i tried growl didnt autostart like i thought it did and after opening it i could get examples working by clicking two buttons.

Comment: If you didn't see the notification, it's probably because its `Display` was set to "[Default]" in Growl. Set it to "Standard".